# “FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource” doesn't work(FACEBOOK JS API)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I called Facebook js methods "FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource",

in IE 9 and chrome, if it works ,the resources could add to the staticresources,I 
can check it in the Facebook Graph API Explorer. but it never happen.

My code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
               FB.init({
                  appId     : '616151165162658', 
                 status     : true,
                 xfbml      : true,
                 version    : "v2.5",
                 cookie     : true
               });  

               FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.setCollectionMode(FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.COLLECT_MANUAL);

               FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource('https://staging.ae-mobile.com:20443/mytest/1.2.3.0/resource/en/spine/cavemen_freespin.swf');
            };</script>
```

I can got the breakpoint of this code, so I can sure the code runed.

The staticresources Explorer
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zihrm.png)

is there any wrong.. why its not showing... have i call that methods in correct place..?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading(); after addstaticroute. and collection mode to COLLECT_AUTOMATIC. Also SSL certificate of your website is not valid.